# Accessing an instance in a dynamically added MC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, instance, movieclip, addchild

I've added a movie clip dynamically using the following code:

```
var apie=new cPie()
apie.x=100
apie.y=100
stage.addChild(apie)
```

I now have a pie on my stage. Yum. Assuming this works like a movie clip placed on the stage by dragging and dropping, I added this in to change an instance in the pie.

```
var apie=new cPie()
apie.x=100
apie.y=100
apie.cherry.gotoAndStop(2)
stage.addChild(apie)
```

cherry is an instance in the cPie movie clip which is another movie clip consisting of 3 frames. I want it to go to the second frame. Usually, doing it this way would work, but when trying with a movie clip added through ActionScript I'm faced with the following runtime error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at pies_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

As always, the error returned doesn't help me solve this problem at all. It's about as obscure as the "implicit coercion" thing, which makes no sense to me not being an English major. What I do know is that I'm doing something wrong and as a result I get this error. The correct way to go about this would be very appreciated.

P.S. I plan to use this in a loop. Please take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the error is caused by the line `apie.cherry.gotoAndStop(2)`. You might have to change that into `apie.getChildByName("cherry").gotoAndStop(2)` but since your pie is a movieclip, children are very often not instantiated right away.

A way to get around that is by waiting for a frame redraw before you try to access children of MovieClips.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you got that error is because `cherry` is not a property or method of the `cPie` object, its the instance name for a child display object of your `cPie` display object container. To access the `cherry` display object you have to use the `cPie` object's inherited `DisplayObjectContainer` methods, namely the `getChildByName()` method. Fortunately this is already explained in another answer by frankhermes, so I'll be explaining another(and arguably better) approach to accessing the child display object in the following example:

CherryPie.as:

```
package display
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class CherryPie extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _cherry:MovieClip;

        public function get cherry():MovieClip
        {
            return _cherry;

        }// end function

        public function CherryPie()
        {
            _cherry = cherryMC;

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Main.as:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            init();

        }// end function

        private function init():void 
        {
            var cherryPie:CherryPie = new CherryPie();
            cherryPie.x = 100;
            cherryPie.y = 100;
            cherryPie.cherry.gotoAndStop(2);
            addChild(cherryPie);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

By creating a base class for your `cherryPie_mc` movie clip, you can create a property called `cherry` and assign the `cherry` child display object to it upon initiating the class. This way you can directly access the `cherry` child display object like:

```
cherryPie.cherry.gotoAndStop(2);
```

as opposed to:

```
cherryPie.getChildByName("cherryMC").gotoAndStop(2);
```

You can set the `CherryPie` class as the `cherryPie_mc` movie clip's base class as follows:

**NOTE: The "Name" in the symbol properties should be "cherryPie_mc"**
[image: Symbol Properties]

Also for those wondering why I didn't set `cherry` as a public property

```
public var cherry:MovieClip;
```

and instead used a getter method to access a private property

```
private var _cherry:MovieClip;

public function get cherry():MovieClip
{
    return _cherry;

}// end function
```

was to make the cherry object read-only which is done by omitting the setter method. The reason I made it read-only was to avoid something like the following:

```
cherryPie.cherry = new FakeCherry();
```

Comment: You kinda flew over my head. I can't really comprehend all of this and especially since I don't want to use packages, so I can't tell how to convert that to normal in-frame AS. Could you provide a solution without packages?

Comment: Personally I would advise against using the timeline, but even if you do, that doesn't mean you can't use your own user defined classes too. Simply create a folder in your source root(in your case probably in the folder containing your "fla" and "swf" files) called "display", then in your "display" folder create an "as" file called `CherryPie` and copy and paste the `CherryPie` class into that file. Then alter the symbol properties for your "cherryPie_mc" movieclip so its matches the screen shot in the answer.